# Is wisdom one type of intelligence, or distinct from it?

Tags: reference-request, intelligence

I am not sure whether this is the best stack exchange for this question, but I couldn't think of a better one. I subscribe to the theory that there are multiple types of intelligence. Is wisdom one type of intelligence? Or is wisdom something that is distinct from intelligence? I think it depends on the definition of intelligence and wisdom. Also, has there been any academic literature on the topic of wisdom and intelligence and the relation between the two?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question that can be answered empirically; possibly there is something you could ask on philosophy.stackexchange.com but check their guidelines first. For questions here, we ask that they are [Framed in Psychology or Neuroscience](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/why-was-my-question-closed-as-not-framed-in-psychology-or-neuroscience), meaning we expect some background for a question. You should be able to demonstrate that your question is relevant to something you have read/heard that you can cite.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom) can be a good place to get some base background - it looks like some psychologists are mentioned there, so if you can read that page and digest what information is there that could be good background for a further question about what you don't understand.